# Sorting shapes method error

Tags: java

```
 public static Shape [] sortShapes(Shape [] shapes) {
    int min;
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        // Assume first element is min

        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < shapes.length; j++) {
            if (shapes[i].compareTo(shapes[j]) == -1) {
                 Shape temp = shapes[i]; 
                shapes[min] = shapes[i];
                shapes[i] = temp;

            }
        }


    }
    return shapes;
}
```

I am trying to write a method that will sort shapes  and return the sorted array
but the output doesnt give me anything, there is no output

Comment: Suggest you put the errors you are getting in the question

Comment: Use `Arrays.sort(shapes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace these :

```
    int temp = shapes[i] ; **
    ...
    shapes[i] =  temp[i] ;
```

With:

```
   Shape temp = shapes[i] ;
   ...
   shapes[i] =  temp ;
```

Because temp is a `Shape` object.

Comment: why would an invalid statement shapes[shapes.length] solve the problem can you explain us???

Comment: `shapes.length` Returns the length of the array. If the array has elements 0-4, it will return 5. Therefore, you never want to attempt to use the `<=` in this case. Your code will throw an array out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Abdelhak The start is irrelevant. You will essentially be calling `array[array.length]` which will *never* work. Using the length of an array will *always* return one more than the last element.

Comment: @Abdelhak for example, once j equals `shapes.length`, and `shapes[j]` is called, you get the out of bounds exception.

Comment: @Abdelhak on your last edit, temp is not an object. You are attempting to declare a Shape object using the word "shapes". You should debug your code *before* you post it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code:

```
if (shapes[min].compareTo(shapes[j]) == -1)
```

The contract of [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is a bit different. There is no guaranty that the results equals `-1`, if it's negative.

```
int temp = shapes[i]; 
shapes[min] = shapes[i];
shapes[i] =  temp[i];
```

This obviously can't work, since `Shape` != `int`. Also  if you want to swap the `Shape`s at position `i` and `min`, there's something wrong with the indices:

```
Shape temp = shapes[i]; // save value at pos i
shapes[i] = shapes[min]; // overwrite value just saved
shapes[min] =  temp; // overwrite other value with saved value
```

Also `return shapes;` is located at the wrong position: You need to guaranty that there is a `return` statement or a uncaugth exception for every possible execution path. Therefore you need to put the statement at the very end of the method, not inside the outer `for` loop.